# Given a value, I want to find this value in one range and then report out a value in the same relative position in a different range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have two ranges on the same sheet, we'll call them Range A and Range B. These ranges are the same size and their location on a sheet is known.

I ultimately need to find a value in Range B. To start with, I have supplied a value in an arbitrary cell. I need to find this value in Range A. Based solely on the relative location of the value in Range A, I need to find a different value in Range B.

I have been able to locate the cell using

```
ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT()ROW(),SUMPRODUCT()COLUMN())
```

function where `C32:H43` is `Range A` and the cell value is `K33`:

```
=ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT((C32:H43=K33)*(ROW(C32:C43))),SUMPRODUCT((C32:H43=K33)*(COLUMN(C32:H32))))
```

In the following picture, the given value is underlined in red. Range A has the value, and it is highlighted in green. I need the value highlighted in Blue in Range B.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only a single match, and the values are numeric, you can use:

```
=SUM((RangeA=[Value_to_Match])*RangeB)
```

or, with a cell reference:

```
=SUM((RangeA=K33)*RangeB)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked; thank you! Although, I admit that I am not sure how it works; can you explain it?

Comment: @ThirstyVoltage I think if you enter the parts of the formula sequentially on a worksheet you will see how it works. First enter `(RangeA=[Value_to_Match])`. Then enter `(RangeA=[Value_to_Match])*RangeB`. Both should result in arrays the same size as the original. In Excel, `True` = `1` and `False` = `0`

Comment: Good idea, I did that and yes, now it makes sense why it worked. Thank you very much.